# Running some shell scripts or adb commands from a Eclipse-plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adb

I'm writing a plug-in for eclipse and almost new to the Java environment, I got basics of how a plug-in works, cleared. Now I need to run some sequence of actions or adb commands on the android device through this plug in. 
Or these can even be shell scripts which I need to invoke as an action handler.
Is there a way to do it? 
Many people have already suggested using Eclipse external tools option, but I don't want to leave it to the end user to configure these options each time a new project is created. In fact, I want these commands to get executed as part of the eclipse environment just like the normal compile and run buttons.

Also is there a better way to do it apart from a eclipse-plugin ?

Comment: anyone , any answers?